# Atribuir valores a um array de struct em Golang

Tags: array, struct, golang

Estou começando a aprender go e preciso preencher popular as diferentes structs com seus valores. Pensei em criar um array de structs e tentar usar um for para preencher os campos mas da um erro de

```
invalid operation: p[1].burst[i] (type int does not support indexing)
```

A dúvida é se é possível fazer algo do tipo pra poder preencher os valores ou se existe alguma outra forma de fazer

```
package main
import (

    "fmt"

)

type process struct{
     burst int
     t_chegada int
}

func main(){

p := make([]process,10)

var n_processo int
fmt.Printf("Número de Processo: ")
fmt.Scanf("%d", &n_processo)

for i := 0; i < n_processo; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("Burst Processo P%d: ", i)
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &p[1].burst[i])
    fmt.Printf("Tempo de Chegada  P%d: ", i)
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &p[2].t_chegada[i])

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar `&p[i].burst` e não `&p[1].burst[i]`:

```
for i := 0; i < n_processo; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("Burst Processo P%d: ", i)
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &p[i].burst)
    fmt.Printf("Tempo de Chegada  P%d: ", i)
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &p[i].t_chegada)
}
```

A iteração ocorre em cada item do slice, então cada `p[i]` é um `process`. Talvez assim fique mais fácil de entender:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    mathrand "math/rand"
)

type process struct {
    burst     int
    t_chegada int
}

func main() {

    p := make([]process, 10)
    for i := range p {
        p[i] = process{
            burst:     mathrand.Int(),
            t_chegada: i,
        }
    }

    fmt.Print(p)
}
```

[É possível testar isso aqui.](https://play.golang.org/p/BcrK6gE7xSh) Para cada `p[i]` existe um `process`. Então usar o `&p[1].burst[i]` não faz sentido algum, exceto se o `burst` também fosse um slice ou array. Mas, como é int, não faz sentido.

Comment: Eu tava com problema pra entender um pouco como funcionava e a sua resposta ajudou bastante. Eu tava com problema pra conseguir ler a entrada do usuário e coloquei `fmt.Scanf` pra cada i do for. Não sei se é a melhor maneira mas funcionou